# GCC - Enable compiler flags only on specific functions

Tags: c, gcc

In a project I'm working on, there's a quadruple-nested for loop in a large file I'm trying to optimize I think would benefit from a compiler unroll with -funroll-all-loops. However, when I add this flag to the compiler, it unrolls the other loops the rest of the file and makes the overall program run more slowly. Is there a way (possibly via a #pragma) to apply compiler flags only to certain functions in the file instead of the entire file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps the real problem is the 4 nested loops...

Answer (score 5):

The GCC [function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) `optimize` can be used to set an optimization option for a single function:

```
void foo(int bar) __attribute__((optimize ("unroll-all-loops")))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest moving that particular function to a separate .c file that can be compiled with the extra options you want to use. This may necessitate creating a "foo_private.h" style header to share between the existing .c file and the new one that allows them to share any variables that were declared as static in the original .c file