# Is it possible to use GCC to compile one section of a code file with specific compiler flags?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization

Is it possible to use GCC to compile one section of a code file with specific compiler flags? For example, suppose I had some functions I was testing. I want those functions to strictly adhere to standards compliance, so I want to compile them with the --pedantic flag. But the code to do the testing issues a lot of warnings on compilation. Is there any way to compile just those specific functions with --pedantic?

Alternatively, suppose I have a carefully written but extremely expensive function that needs to run as fast as possible. How could I compile just that function (and a few others) with -Ofast, and compile the rest of the program with -O2 or -O3?

Comment: Put those functions in separate files and build them with separate flags - would be the simple solution.  "the code to do the testing issues a lot of warnings" - so fix them already - don't wait or make excuses - *fix* compiler warnings (and start building with `-Werror`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCC - Enable compiler flags only on specific functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925989/gcc-enable-compiler-flags-only-on-specific-functions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is, actually, using `#pragma optimize` statements, or using `__attribute__((optimize("-O3")))` All the optimize options can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options).

A simple example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>


// Using attribute
__attribute__((optimize("-O3"))) void fast_function_attribute()
{
    printf("Now calling a slow function, compiled with -O3 flags.\n");
}


__attribute__((optimize("-O1"))) void slow_function_attribute()
{
    printf("Now calling a slow function, compiled with -O1 flags.\n");
}


// Using #pragma
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("-O3")


void fast_function_pragma()
{
    printf("This will be another fast routine.\n");
}


#pragma GCC pop_options


#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("-O1")


void slow_function_pragma()
{
    printf("This will be another slow routine.\n");
}


#pragma GCC pop_options


int main(void)
{
    fast_function_attribute();
    slow_function_attribute();
    fast_function_pragma();
    slow_function_pragma();
}
```

If you are using different compilers, I would highly recommend wrapping them with macros (or using pragma statements rather than `__attribute__` to avoid any compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
#include <iostream>

#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wpedantic"
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")
void bob(){
  std::cerr<<"Sandwich maker!"<<std::endl;
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#pragma GCC pop_options

int main(){
  bob();
}
```

The `push_options` and `diagnostic push` saves the optimization and diagnostic flags, respectively, prior to altering those to pedantic and `O0` (or `O1`, `O2`, `O3`, `Os`, `Og`). The `pop` pragmas restore the original settings.

More details on optimization pragmas are [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas) and details on diagnostic pragmas are [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).

Answer (score 0):

GCC allows this in some cases, but not all.

For optimization options, you can use the [`optimize` function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-optimize-function-attribute) or [equivalent `#pragma` directive](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#index-pragma-GCC-optimize).

For warning options, it’s less reliable. I think there’s only [a pragma](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#index-pragma_002c-diagnostic) for it and not a function attribute, and it apparently doesn’t support all warnings.

For options other than warnings or optimizations, I don’t know of any way to do this other than using separate files.